# How to recognize 105° C rated electrolytic capacitors?

Tags: electrolytic-capacitor

If there is no explicit working temperature printed on the body of the capacitor can we assume is always 85°C?

I have to replace a few of 1980s capacitors (manufactured by ROE, Frako, and Philips), and can't find any technical datasheets about them to decode the marking codes they use.

[image: ROE L2 EKM Capacitor 1000/16]

*Added another example of suspect 105°C capacitor:
[image: FRAKO 47/40 L3]

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to replace them with 105 or 125 °C rated caps anyway.

Comment: Tip: When you are specifying degrees (°) you need to specify the units. i.e. °C or °F. I fixed your question.

Comment: @Transistor Thx

Comment: @Hearth Yes, I'm aware of that, thank you.

Comment: @Transistor does any capacitor manufacturer anywhere in the world (even in the USA) use °F to spec their capacitors?

Comment: Also, what would be the point of a 105°F rated cap? That would probably require active cooling.

Answer (score 10):

> *If there is no explicit working temperature printed on the body of the
> capacitor can we assume is always 85°C?*

Roederstein EKM capacitors are 105°C rated as per this [Vishay-Roederstein capacitor replacement table](https://www.vishay.com/docs/28398/replacetabaxradsmd.pdf): -

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for this document. This confirm my suspect about this capacitor. I already noticed Vishay is still currently using the ROE old marking for at least some its radio suppression capacitors and I was optimistic about finding something for the electrolytic ones, but for Frako e Philips maybe is harder.

Comment: @Coriolanus I'm sure they'll be out there - it took me 10 minutes to find the Roederstein one and old Philips parts are usually found under EPCOS and more recently TDK I believe.